# MySQL BETWEEN query - which part uses index?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing, database-optimization

Say I have a table `foo(bar:int)` with a normal btree index on `bar`, and the table contains 100 rows (with `bar` having values 2 to 101). When running the following query, how does MySQL decide whether to do the `>=` or the `<=` first?

```
SELECT bar from foo where bar BETWEEN 0 AND 1
```

If it did the `>=` then it would scan all 100 rows. On the other hand if it did the `<=` it would do 0 scans. Is there a way to specify which to do first?

This is particularly relevant for me for `datetime` range queries on very large tables containing years of historic data and where the timeframe requested is close to the current time. If it did the `<=` first then there would be a huge scan on the many years worth of data. For example:

```
SELECT * from table 
WHERE instant BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE);
```

Comment: If I answered your question please accept it as an answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi Michail, thanks very much for your response. I will accept if it's answered my question, I just need to study it a bit more to understand :)

Comment: Sure let me know if you need more clarifications :)

Comment: More time needed or you forgot me :P? Seriously if you need anything to be more clarified - just let me know :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I am really interested in finding an accurate answer, I've just not spent long enough reading about it. I keep rereading your answer thinking 'ok, i'm with you', and then I lose it in the 'cases' section. I'm not sure we are referring to the same type of 'scan' - I mean having to interrogate a mysql record rather than using an index (since for a range, mysql can only use the index for part of the search). Is that what you're referring to or when you say scan do you mean traversing the tree?

Comment: scan means following the horizontal links of leafs in a B+ tree. As I said depending on what type of index this is is (clustered vs non-clustered) this means disk scan too in the case of clustered. The mysql records in the asked range will be read no matter what - because you are doing a WHERE with a range condition (>=, =<, >= and <=). I will rewrite my answer in a more clear way at some point but I believe my answer is as accurate as it can get given the generality of your question.

Comment: I agree the mysql records /in/ the range will always be read, my goal however is to minimise the number of records required to be read that are not in the range. Minimising this depends which side of the `BETWEEN` is executed first. In the case of `bar BETWEEN 0 and 1`, using the RHS would result in no records read, but if the LHS was used it would be 100 records read. From what you say in your answer (excluding the last paragraph) it sounds to me like it will always do the LHS first, is that right?

Comment: What seems that it is not clear to you yet is that the BETWEEN 0 and 1 is not a left and a right part .. it is a completely different query and happens together. Having said that between/range queries hit the B-tree in a very different way than just >=0 alone or <=1 alone (my 3 cases). So we cannot talk about order of things happening when there is no left and right

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly: When a B-tree index is created usually it is a B+tree 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree

[image: B+ Tree representation]

Wikipedia:*"A simple B+ tree example linking the keys 1–7 to data values d1-d7. The linked list (red) allows rapid in-order traversal."*

That means that the smallest element in the range is found (in your case the earliest date) in approximately log_b(N) time and then
there are k hops from all the leafs of the B+ tree till all the elements in the range are exhausted.

k is the number of elements in the range that exist in the database and not all the possible values, N is the height of the tree (in Wikipedia example it is 2)  and b is the branching factor of the tree (in Wikipedia example it is 3)

**Edit:**
Cases:

- In the case of only foo<=1 it goes in the B+tree and doesn't find anything so we have 0 scans.
- In the case of only foo>=0 it will not find 0 but the first in it's values and it will go to 2 in your case. Then it will do the 100 scans
- When you have 'foo 0 between 40' it is like foo<=40 AND foo>=0, so it will go to the first, in your case to 2 and then do (38hopes/scans assuming that all the values are in the database). In other words, **they are not executed separately**, so they will use the index together!

In general Sql servers have optimizers that can detect ranges and rewrite your queries by putting your ANDs in the right order. They also keep track of the query performance and they decide after estimating cost plans which execution plan to follow. If you have SQL Server you can see all these plans with any query.

Comment: "38hopes/scans" --- where does this number come from?

Comment: 40-2 because you have stored values 2-101

Comment: B+Tree is a sorted structure. Why to scan elements sequentially?

Comment: The scan will be sequential if the index is clustered or in other words the values for bar can be found in exactly the same order in the disk. If it is not clustered it means that there are pointers to the actual positions in the harddisk. That will involve some more seek time in the disk before the scans happen. There are many details that I am omitting here.. that I am sure you know too with 10 years of experience in RDBMS but they are way out of the scope of the question :)

Comment: [Question was removed] Yeah but in his second query the index is not self contained he needs */all of the fields so it will touch the disk. If we have an index on bar, we will have to touch the disk only in the case that the index doesn't fit fully in main memory/RAM.

Comment: yep, for some reason I did not notice the second query and thought it's all about the first one. I need glasses :-S